# is "ip route list | grep docker0" a reliable way to get the docker host ip?

Tags: networking, docker

I'm using this code to inject the docker host ip into my container. It seems to work but I'm not sure exactly what `ip route list` does and if this will work on other environments and if the ip param will always be 9th.

```
docker_host_ip=$(ip route list | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}')

docker_compose="
  version: '3.5'
  services:
    app:
      extra_hosts:
        - dockerhost:$docker_host_ip
"

echo "$docker_compose" | docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f /dev/stdin \
  up
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks reliable. This `ip route list` shows all the configured routes on your system and the `src` attribute restricts the potential sources for the target IPs, which is the docker0 IP in this case (look here for more info about `src`: [ip route show src field](https://serverfault.com/questions/451601/ip-route-show-src-field)).

Another way would be to get the network interface details via `ifconfig docker0` or `ip a show dev docker0`.